# CONSTRAINT based on field value

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

So I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE meta (
    id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,  
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    value LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id, type, name),

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

the type field can only have 3 possible values: "article", "user" or "page". And I have 3 tables for each of those content types.

How can I add a constraint that tells mysql to remove the "meta" row if the type is "article" and id matches a article id form the articles table? And two more contraints for the "user" and "page" types.

Right now I have:

```
CONSTRAINT article_meta FOREIGN KEY(id)
    REFERENCES articles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

but it doesn't take in consideration the "type" field, so the row gets deleted regardless of the type value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. If you look at [the syntax for a CREATE TABLE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html), foreign keys have to have this form:

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
      [index_name] (index_col_name,...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
      [MATCH FULL | MATCH PARTIAL | MATCH SIMPLE]
      [ON DELETE {RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION}]
      [ON UPDATE {RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION}]
```

So you can't (say) create a foreign key on `WHEN type = '...' THEN id ELSE NULL END` (because the foreign key has to be on a column-name, or multiple column-names, not arbitrary expressions), and you can't (say) describe a foreign key as only applying `WHEN type = '...'` (because there's no syntax for that).

But I wonder — are you sure it's a good idea to have a single `meta` table with metadata for all of these different tables? If the tables have enough in common, semantically, that it makes sense for them to share a `meta`, then they should also probably share some sort of parent table, `entity`, that's responsible for their overall IDs (in which case you can use multi-column foreign keys to ensure that `type`s match and everything); but if, as I suspect, they really have nothing in common semantically, then they shouldn't have a single shared `meta` table, but rather, there should be an `article_meta` table, a `user_meta` table, and a `page_meta` table. No?

Comment: yes, I created 3 separate meta tables, but I thought I could stuff all meta data into one table, because there isn't that much data :)